# How do I select this element in Seleno/Selenium

Tags: selenium, seleno

I am trying to use Seleno (and therefore Selenium) to do some UI testing in my project.

In my rendered page is the following link

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <a class="btn btn-md btn-default btn-success col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" href="XXXXXX" id="btnInternal">Secured User</a>
</div>
```

However, when I call

```
var userLink = By.PartialLinkText("Secured User");
return Navigate.To<UserDashboard>(userLink);
```

it does not work (I started with By.LinkText, and that didn't work, so I thought PartialLinkText might be more forgiving)

In either case, I end up with the NoSuchElementException

I can't use the CSS or other selectors AFAIK, because there are many other links on the page using the same styling.

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` usually means the object is 1. contained within a `<frame>` or `<iframe>` or 2. Not yet visible on the page.  To solve 1. you can use SwitchTo().Frame(IDENTIFIER).  To solve 2. you can implement a wait for the element you wish to interact with.

Comment: Its not using a frame, and the page is pretty static and I can see it on the page during the test run.

I think its something about the nesting of the various elements on the page causing confusion in the selenium selector

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the byLink text, but I was able to get it with an XPath query.